# When using Spring boot and Spring JPA - why can't I get schema generation for entities in dependency?

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, dependencies

I have a Spring Boot maven project using spring-boot-starter-jpa which I've been using to auto generate database tables for an in memory h2 database for integration tests.

This worked perfectly until I refactored the @Entity classes to a separate maven module to enable reuse across two other projects.

Once the Entity classes were included as a maven dependency instead of being in the same module, the table creation no longer works. I have the following in the application.properties feil@

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

Spring is able to inject the @Repository classes, which are standard CrudRepository interfaces.

I've changed my application class to have:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.acme.mypackage")
```

Where the @Entity classes contained in the dependency are in the com.acme.mypackage package. This hasn't worked.

When using the h2 console after starting the app, I can see that the tables for the entities that come from the dependency are not being created.

How can I get spring boot to automatically generate the database tables for @Entity classes contained in a maven dependency?

Comment: Try `@EntityScan("my.entity.package")` rather than/in addition to `@EnableJpaRepositories("my.repository.package")` . https://springbootdev.com/2017/11/13/what-are-the-uses-of-entityscan-and-enablejparepositories-annotations/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use @EntityScan to tell Spring Data JPA that your entities are in a different package:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan ("com.acme.mypackage")
```

Please find the official documentation here:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-separate-entity-definitions-from-spring-configuration

@EnableJpaRepositories with the package name must be used if your repositories are in a place that's not below the route hierarchie where your SpringBootApplication class is.